# Difference between setState class comp and function comp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to update a class-based component to a function component, but I'm facing issues with the state. In the function component, the state is not updated. After trying to debug this, there seems to be something wrong with this line: `setState(func(...args))`. Any suggestions?

Note: `_.` is lodash

```
export default class BPM extends React.Component {
  state = { ..._.cloneDeep(bpmFlowInitialValues) };

  render() {
    const chart = this.state;
    const stateActions = _.mapValues(
      callbacks,
      (func) =>
        (...args) =>
          this.setState(func(...args))
    );

    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <>
        <ShapesHeader />
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
          <Flowchart chart={chart} stateActions={stateActions} />
          <Sidebar selected={this.state.selected} />
        </Box>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Function comp:

```
export default function BPM() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    ..._.cloneDeep(bpmFlowInitialValues),
  });

  const stateActions = _.mapValues(
    callbacks,
    (func) =>
      (...args) =>
        setState(func(...args))
  );

  console.log('state', state);

  return (
    <>
      <ShapesHeader />
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
        <Flowchart chart={state} stateActions={stateActions} />
        <Sidebar selected={state && state.selected} />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: the state value doesn't update

Comment: Try wrapping lines 6-13 of the function component in a `React.useEffect(()=>{ <lines here> }, [])` to see if it works

Comment: already tried bro